# Как регулируется ширина содержимого отчёта ssrs в iframe?

Tags: html, css, ssrs

Делаю обложку в DIRECTUM. Поместил в маленький блок div простой отчёт диаграмму в iframe

```html
<iframe  frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width=100% height="305"src="http://servername/SSRS/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%2fReportToDirectum2&rs:Command=Render"  ></iframe>
```

но в итоге вижу вот такое 
[image]

Comment: у вас кнопка печати стоит там, в отчете. У меня не появляется, его надо как то включить?\